# VBA (Word) - can i see if application is already open

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been having experiencing an issue with Word VBA where, if the Application is already open, it would just crash and doesn't do any further steps. I've been surfing the Net trying to figure this out, but no luck. The error appears at the `o.Workbooks.Open` line:

```
Dim o as Excel.Application
o.Workbooks.Open (ActiveDocument.Path + "\Data.xlsm")
```

Error message is

> c:\fol\data.xlsm is already open or doesn't exist

It basically saves the data that was entered in Word text boxes. Note: All code afterwards works fine, this is the line where it breaks. I've tried using `On Error` that it would just stop, but it doesn't seem to work :/ 
Any ideas?

Comment: More code is needed here. And an exact error message.

Comment: And are you trying to see if the Excel Application is open, or whether a specific workbook is open in an Excel Application on your computer, or whether a specific workbook (perhaps on a shared drive) is open in an Excel Application on **any** computer?

Comment: Does somewhere in your code close the Workbook and quit the Excel process? You can go by `On Error Resume Next`, then `Set` App/Workbook object to see if they are `Nothing`. Not **Nothing** means opened already.

Comment: And do you mean Application or the specific workbook?